# How to configure the sct-issuer-config parameter in a secure conversation scenario

Tags: wso2, ws-security, wso2-identity-server

I´m working in a secureconversation scenario using the STS service in the WSO2 Identity Server 4.6.0 secure with scenario 5 and a webservice in the WSO2 Application Server 5.2.1 secure with the scenario 15.

When I request a token from WSO2 IS I recieve this error:

```
SEVERE: errorInObtainingToken
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Expected parameter missing : "sct-issuer-config" 
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:375)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:555)
    at org.apache.rahas.client.STSClient.requestSecurityToken(STSClient.java:150)
org.apache.rahas.TrustException: Error in obtaining token from : "https://localhost:9449/services/wso2carbon-sts"
    at org.apache.rahas.client.STSClient.requestSecurityToken(STSClient.java:159)
```

Any idea about how configure the sct-issuer-config parameter in my code? It´s client side or server side?

EDIT: I put the configuration not in the service deployed in WSO2 AS but in the STS service deployed in the WSO2 IS and the error change. Now it´s this:

```
org.apache.rahas.TrustException: Error in obtaining token from : "https://localhost:9449/services/wso2carbon-sts"
    at org.apache.rahas.client.STSClient.requestSecurityToken(STSClient.java:159)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: java.lang.RuntimeException: Undefined 'Unsupported WS-SecureConversation version' resource property
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:375)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:555)
    at org.apache.rahas.client.STSClient.requestSecurityToken(STSClient.java:150)
    ... 6 more
```

Thanks.

Comment: To verify whether the sct-issuer-config param is added, open up carbon_home/repository/deployment/server/servicemetafiles/<service-group-name>.xml, and make sure that this param is there.

Comment: check the edit in my question...now the error change to Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: java.lang.RuntimeException: Undefined 'Unsupported WS-SecureConversation version' resource property

Answer (score 0):

`sct-issuer-config` should be added to your service in AS as an axis2 parameter when you secure it with a security scenario via UI. It usually looks as follows. You could try adding this parameter to your service manually, and try.

```
  <parameter name="sct-issuer-config" type="2">
     <sct-issuer-config>
        <cryptoProperties>
           <crypto provider="org.wso2.carbon.security.util.ServerCrypto">
              <property name="org.wso2.carbon.security.crypto.alias">wso2carbon</property>
              <property name="org.wso2.carbon.security.crypto.privatestore">wso2carbon.jks</property>
           </crypto>
        </cryptoProperties>
        <keyComputation>3</keyComputation>
        <proofKeyType>BinarySecret</proofKeyType>
        <addRequestedAttachedRef/>
        <addRequestedUnattachedRef/>
     </sct-issuer-config>
  </parameter>
  <parameter name="token-canceler-config" type="2">
     <token-canceler-config/>
     <parameter name="token-canceler-config" type="1">
        <token-canceler-config/>
     </parameter>
  </parameter>
```

Comment: I put this config in the HelloService.xml file restart the AS server and check via UI that the parameter is ok. Then restart the IS to and the problem persist....but now I have another error: org.apache.rahas.TrustException: Error in obtaining token from : "https://localhost:9449/services/wso2carbon-sts"
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: First Element must contain the local name, Envelope , but found html

...more                                                            that disappear when I login into WSO2 IS and update the security policy in the STS service.